# How do I install Graphite on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, graphite

Ubuntu 13.10 now includes `graphite-web` package. But how should I set up Graphite, after installing the package? I only find Ubuntu 12.04 tutorials, which of course don't use the .deb packages. I'd rather not stumble through all the steps myself trial-and-error style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

... and immediately after posting I remembered to check `/usr/share/doc/graphite-web/README.Debian` which seems to have comprehensive instructions.

In addition to the README, I installed the `graphite-carbon` package, and enabled it by modifying `/etc/default/graphite-carbon` (change `false` to `true`), then running `sudo /etc/init.d/carbon-cache start`. After that the daemon was listening on tcp port 2003.